# Distribution list in Secure group does not recieve alerts

Tags: list, alert, groups

We have a secure SD group name BNPAdmin, on which we have set alerts on a list.

There is a distribution list named BNP@server.com.
We have added BNP@server.com as a member of BNPAdmin but the mailbox is not recieving emails.

Could someone please suggest me something

Answer (score 0):

You mean that all members of a security group are not receiving emails? Can you verify that the security group is mail-enabled?

If you are using Office365 you should go to Admin>Office365>Users and groups>Security groups.